# Copy files from host to container when container starts on any host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to copy files from host to Docker container when I run the container on any host.

here is my *Dockerfile*

```
FROM tomcat:9
EXPOSE 8080
ADD ./target/app.war /tmp/myapp.war
RUN unzip /tmp/myapp.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp
ENTRYPOINT ["cp", "-r", "/data/*", "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp/data"]
```

After building the docker image
`docker build -t myappimage .`

I am running it with:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=d:/data,destination=/data --rm -it -p 8081:8080 myappimage
```

but this throws error `cp: cannot stat '/data/*': No such file or directory`

I am not sure why mounting is not working, it should copy all files from my host directory **d:/data** to Docker container directory **/data** when a container starts.

Answer (score 0):

This command in `ENTRYPOINT` is run in Docker container.

You can try:

```
FROM tomcat:9
EXPOSE 8080
ADD ./target/app.war /tmp/myapp.war
RUN unzip /tmp/myapp.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp
COPY /data /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp/data/
```

Comment: it will copy at the time of building image.

Answer (score 0):

I hope `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp/data` directory exist in image prior to copying. The command seems to working fine on my machine (Mac). Not sure if it's the `d:/` that is causing the issue.

Also you can try using the `-v` option with a `z` flag (It solved the same issue for me), assuming you are inside `d:` directory

```
docker run -v "$(pwd)"/data:/data:z --rm -it -p 8081:8080 myappimage
```

With `-v` it will create an endpoint for you. You can read [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#differences-between--v-and---mount-behavior)